# Python Repetition Structures and Files

Tags: python, file, structure, repeat

I have a question about my python program . I have trouble finding the total and ntotal in this program. Rest works fine. Is there any way i can fix this? I have this program due soon. I'd appreciate any tips I can get :D Thanks

```
midSalary = 50000
maxSalary = 60000

def main():

    inFile = open('program7.txt', 'r')    
    lineRead = inFile.readline()
    total = 0.0
    ntotal = 0.0
    count = 0

    while lineRead != '':
       words = lineRead.split()
       for word in words:
          num = float(word)
          total += num
          count += 1          
          print("\nFaculty Member # ",count, ": $" , format(num, '.2f'), sep ="")
          if num >= maxSalary:
              payIncrease(num, .04)
          elif num >= midSalary:
              payIncrease(num, .07)
          else:
              payIncrease(num , .055)
       lineRead = inFile.readline()
   #averagePayRaise = (ntotal - total) / count
    inFile.close()
    for divider in range(45):
        print("-", end ='')
    print("\nTotal Faculty payroll : $", format(total , ",.2f"),sep ="")
    print("The New Total Faculty payroll : $", format(ntotal , ",.2f"),sep ="")
    print("Average Pay Raise : $", format(averagePayRaise, ",.2f"), sep ="")

def payIncrease(amount, prcnt):
    print("Pay Raise Percent : ", format(prcnt*100, ".1f")+"%")
    total = 0.0
    ntotal = 0.0
    count = 0
    salRaise = amount * prcnt
    newSal = amount + salRaise
    print("Pay Raise : $", format(salRaise, ',.2f'), sep ="")
    print("New Salary : $", format(newSal, ',.2f'), sep = "")
    total += amount
    count += 1
    ntotal += newSal
    averagePayRaise = (ntotal - total) / count

main()
```

Comment: I get the solution as 0 for em

Comment: Could you show the input, the expected output and the current output ?

Comment: Total Faculty payroll : $1,310,555.15
The New Total Faculty payroll : $0.00
Average Pay Raise : $-59,570.69

I get that once i updated my code as one of the answer below said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, names that you assign to in Python are *local* to the function in which they are declared. So, if you have:

```
def main():
    total = 0

def payIncrease():
    total = 0
    total += amount
```

then you have *two* independent values named `total`. One way to solve this is to make it global:

```
total = 0

def main():
    global total
    total = 0

def payIncrease():
    global total
    total += amount
```

Note that you don't want to assign `total = 0` inside `payIncrease()`, because that would reset your running total to 0. You probably added that when you broke out your code into the `payIncrease()` function because Python gave you an error without that.

Comment: do i have to make ntotal a global variable as well to fix the error?

Comment: What do you think? Does it work if you don't do that?

Comment: i need to look at my code again. I'm getting negative number for average pay raise and my ntotal is printing the last newSal

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct operator, such as `+=` instead of `=`.

Comment: my total is double of what it should be for some reason. my ntotal is showing up right. :( thanks man for your help. but i fixed it :D thanks man you're awesome

Answer (score 0):

```
def payIncrease(salary):
    if current_sal >= maxSalary: return 0.04
    if current_sal >= midSalary: return 0.07
    return 0.055

def processSalaryData(line):
    """take a line and return current salary and new salary (note that a line is actually just a float)"""
    try:
        current_sal = float(line)
    except ValueError:
         return None

    return current_sal,current_sal + current_sal*payIncrease(current_sal)

def main():
    salaryData = [processSalaryData(line) for line in open("salaries.txt")]
    salaryData = filter(None,salaryData) #filter out invalid data
    adjustments = [b-a for a,b in salaryData]
    old_salaries,new_salaries = zip(*salaryData)

    print "OLD TOTAL PAYROLL :",sum(old_salaries)
    print "NEW TOTAL PAYROLL :",sum(new_salaries)
    print "AVG ADJUSTMENT:",sum(adjustments)/len(adjustments)
    print "MAX SALARY:",max(new_salaries)
    print "MIN SALARY:",min(new_salaries)
```

Comment: nope I wrote it. I tried to simplify my code by calling another function. Otherwise it worked just fine

Comment: thanks man! that works as well. Wish i could write code like you python gurus! one day i guess lol